# RecyclerView with null model

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Recently, a new error occured while trying to get data from Firebase Realtime Database into a `RecyclerView`!

I am having an Activity called `GetReadyListActivity.java`, a Model called `GetReadyListModel.java` and a ViewHolder called `GetReadyViewHolder.java`. I also have my Activity's XML which includes the RecyclerView called `activity_get_ready_list.xml` and my RecyclerView Item layout called `recyclerview_get_ready_list.xml`. I provide the code below!

I think the error pops up due to the Model containing a null object whilst getting the status (see LogCat).

**Logcat:**
`2018-12-06 19:06:37.974 19148-19148/com.myapp.something.app W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 02 found on class com.myapp.something.app.GetReadyListModel
2018-12-06 19:06:37.974 19148-19148/com.myapp.something.app W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 01 found on class com.myapp.something.app.GetReadyListModel
2018-12-06 19:06:37.974 19148-19148/com.myapp.something.app W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 03 found on class com.myapp.something.app.GetReadyListModel
2018-12-06 19:06:37.976 19148-19148/com.myapp.something.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.something.app, PID: 19148
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
        at com.myapp.something.app.GetReadyListViewHolder.setDetails(GetReadyListViewHolder.java:27)
        at com.myapp.something.app.GetReadyListActivity$1.populateViewHolder(GetReadyListActivity.java:51)
        at com.myapp.something.app.GetReadyListActivity$1.populateViewHolder(GetReadyListActivity.java:48)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:177)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1888)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:407)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:907)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:709)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:641)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:893)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6361)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
2018-12-06 19:06:37.980 1163-1208/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.myapp.something.app/.GetReadyListActivity`

**GetReadyListModel.java: My Model Class**

```
public class GetReadyListModel {
    String title, desc;
    Boolean status;

    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public GetReadyListModel() {}

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

}
```

**GetReadyListViewHolder.java: My View Holder Class**

```
public class GetReadyListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public GetReadyListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setDetails(Context ctx, String title, String desc, Boolean status) {
        TextView mTitle = mView.findViewById(R.id.getReadyListTitle);
        TextView mDesc = mView.findViewById(R.id.getReadyListDesc);
        Switch mStatus = mView.findViewById(R.id.getReadyListStatus);

        mTitle.setText(title);
        mDesc.setText(desc);
        mStatus.setChecked(status);

    }
}
```

**GetReadyListActivity.java: The activity which contains the RecyclerView**

```
public class GetReadyListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_ready_list);

        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.get_ready_list_app_bar_layout);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("GetReady");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.getReadyListRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("tools");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<GetReadyListModel, GetReadyListViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<GetReadyListModel, GetReadyListViewHolder>(GetReadyListModel.class, R.layout.recyclerview_get_ready_list_row, GetReadyListViewHolder.class, mDatabaseReference) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(GetReadyListViewHolder viewHolder, GetReadyListModel model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getDesc(), model.getStatus());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public GetReadyListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_get_ready_list_row, parent, false);
                return new GetReadyListViewHolder(view);
            }
        };

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

As one can see: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference` is fired when you start the activity. So I think it is a problem with the Model Class, but I am not able to find the reason why.

Any help is appreciated
Max

Comment: Hi Max! Please highlight the exact line of code at which this NPE occurs.

Comment: what value set in your status? its boolean but set null in that.